# How do I calculate the changed value after rotating the canvas rectangle in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, math, canvas

Maybe it's simple math, but I'm asking a question because it's not easy to find a way to calculate.

I'm drawing a rectangle using `canvas` and I can rotate it using `canvas.rotate`.
If have `Rect` as follows and I rotate it 30 degrees, how can I calculate the `Rect` value(rect LTRB) after rotation?

```
    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTRB(100,100,200,200);

    final degrees = 30;
    final radians = degrees * math.pi / 180;

    canvas.translate(100,100); // left top pivot
    canvas.rotate(radians);        
    canvas.translate(-100,-100)
    // after rotate, rect left,rop, right, bottom value = ?
```

Comment: Where is the rotation center ? And what do you call the offset, exactly ?

Comment: I modified my post. 
To be exact, I should calculate the LTRB value of Rect, not offset.

Comment: That still does not really tell me where the rotation center is.

Comment: better use `Matrix4` - there is a built-in `MatrixUtils` class for things you need

Answer (score 2):

Let `C` be the rotation center. Any corner `P` maps to

```
(cos Θ (P.X-C.X) - sin Θ (P.Y-C.Y) + C.X, sin Θ (P.X-C.X) + cos Θ (P.Y-C.Y) + C.Y)
```

Take the minima and maxima for the four corners to get the bounding box.